# Unix shell bit select

Tags: shell, binary

How can I calculate bit selection from shell?

Suppose I've got something like: `i[m:l]`

`i` is an integer, `m` is the MSB portion of the bit select and `l` is the LSB portion of the bit select, e.g.:

- `250[1:0]` - would return the 2 LSB bits of "250", and answer will be "2"
- `250[7:2]` - would return the 6 MSB bits of "250", and answer will be "62"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how portable this is, but Bash and KSH at least support bitwise operations (left & right shift, bitwise AND and OR), and exponentiation. So you can use those directly to do bitmasks.

```sh
#! /bin/sh

extract_bits() {
    msb=$1 ; lsb=$2 ; num=$3
    # Number of bits required
    len=$(( $msb + 1 - $lsb ))
    # Bitmask == 2^len - 1
    mask=$(( 2 ** $len - 1 ))
    # Left-shift mask, bitand, right-shift result
    echo $(( ( num & ( $mask << $lsb ) ) >> $lsb ))
}

extract_bits 1 0 250
extract_bits 7 2 250
```

(As to whether it's a good idea to be doing this at all in a shell script, well, I'm not convinced.)